# Is there a faster way than using sorted or a loop?

Tags: python-3.x

Given the dictionary:

```
my_dict = {
'person': [{
    'f_name': 'foo',
    'l_name': 'bar'
}],
'person_1': [{
    'f_name': 'foo 1',
}],
'person_2': [],
```

}

the expected output is 2 which is the max length of the list which can be done like this:

```
print(len(sorted(list(my_dict.values()), key=len, reverse=True)[0])) # complexity: N Log n
```

or

```
print(max([len(v) for v in a.values()])) # complexity: O(n)
```

Comment: How do you expect find a maximum in an unsorted list in less than O(n)?

Comment: Here if I use max then the complexity will be O(n^2), so is there any efficient way to achieve the target?

Comment: Why do you think the complexity is `O(n^2)`?

Comment: Here max needs a list so that is O(n) and there is one loop inside the max which makes n^2 which makes O(n^2).

Comment: No. The list comprehension is calculated before hand. That uses the `len()` method which is O(1). Afterwards finding the max in the list created by the list-comprehension is again O(n). Which makes the the whole thing O(n) + O(n) = O(n).

Comment: ok. Thanks for the detailed explanation. Really appreciated.